# Is one correlation coefficient possible for 3 variables?

Tags: correlation, multivariate-analysis

I have three variables (`X`,`Y` and `Z`) which were measured on three different days. So, I have `X_1`,`X_2`,`X_3`,`Y_1`,`Y_2`,`Y_3`,`Z_1`,`Z_2` and `Z_3`

I am wondering whether I could obtain a single correlation coefficient for `X`'s, `Y`'s and `Z`'s, 3 correlation coefficients in total. So, I can compare these 3 coefficients.

Here is the heading of my data

```
X_1  X_2  X_3  Y_1  Y_2 Y_3  Z_1 Z_2 Z_3
12  10.5  9.9 27.5 27.1 26.9 4.3 4.2 3.8
```

Is that possible?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want the correlation between (e.g.) $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ and $(y_1, y_2, y_3)$ where each subscripted value is a single measurement and similarly for $(x, z)$ pairs and $(y, z)$ pairs. You can do that but note that 3 values is not much information for calculating a correlation.. (I don't read this as a question about copulas, but different interpretations seem possible. Your title seems to imply that you want one correlation, but your text says three. Please clarify.)

Comment: What I want to do is similar to this. What is that method called? PS: I have 30 observation per variable, 270 in total

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how your descriptions tie up at all. If you just have 30 observations x 9 variables, what logic groups them as $x, y, z$?. Why not show the data and explain the substantive set-up? (What is "this"?)

Comment: That is because I have three variables (X,Y and Z) and each variable was measured before and after the treatment (repeated measures). Therefore I called them X1, X2 and X3 and so on. Please see my edited post

Comment: Depends a little on your software, but in programs I know restructuring your data from 30 x 9 to (3 x 30) x 3 would be advisable. This is often called a reshape to long.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want to do is find a correlation measure between random vectors $X = (X_1,X_2,X_3)$, $Y = (Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)$, and $Z = (Z_1,Z_2,Z_3)$.

From what I know on this topic you can:

- consider the random vector $V = (X,Y) = (X_1,X_2,X_3,Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)$, fit an empirical copula to it, then non-linear random projections of the empirical copula and compute the largest canonical correlation of the projections; this approach is described in [this NIPS paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.7717v2.pdf);
- consider the random vector $V = (X,Y) = (X_1,X_2,X_3,Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)$, fit an empirical copula to it, then use a distance to compare the fitted empirical copula to the independence copula using some distance (for example, optimal transport/earth mover distance as described in [this ICASSP paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.08144v1.pdf)).

But, these two approaches loose the fact that X and Y are distinct objects. Indeed, a copula cannot exist for that, but the independence one (cf. Genest, C., Quesada Molina, J. et Rodríguez Lallena, J. [1995]. De l'impossibilité de construire des lois à marges multidimensionnelles données à partir de copules. Comptes rendus de l'Académie des sciences de Paris, 320, 723–726.).

I never seen this before, but you could try to fit a copula on $X = (X_1,X_2,X_3)$ and another one on $(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)$, and then use [Kendall distributions](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.332.1876&rep=rep1&type=pdf) to transform these two copulas on two uniforms in [0,1], and then measure correlation on these two uniforms. I will detail this approach once I have workout the details.